# How to get WSDL for REST API?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, wsdl, api-design

I am writting API-REST, and working with Sap progrommers.
They need me to give them wsdl files.
No clue how to start even.
Can someone help me?
 Thanks

Comment: REST API's don't have WSDL ....

Comment: marc_s, you are right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First understand what is WSDL according to standard definition

> WSDL is an XML format for describing network services as a set of endpoints operating on messages containing either document-oriented or procedure-oriented information. The operations and messages are described abstractly, and then bound to a concrete network protocol and message format to define an endpoint.

So basically WSDL is metadata of your service which provide the description about any service. For running any service there is need of three basic component

1. Address(url)
2. Binding(protocol)
3. Service (Which service is running on that address.)

The cumulative is known as **endpoints**.

Since Restful service only use http(s) protocol to run service so there is not much information is needed for restful services only address of restful service is enough.Hence there is not need of metadata and WSDL document in Restful service. But for other kind of service (like **SOAP** based) built on WCF framework WSDL document is necessary to expose there information to client so that client can utilize that WSDL document to customize itself according to service.

Comment: sure,but I can't find where is the place to vote

Comment: hey I need to expose my model class via url. How to do that? any idea? for soap based we can do like "url?wsdl" then what for rest api?